# How to split company savings

Tags: salary

I am saving my company an average of 25k per year on a project I just completed.  How should the savings of 25k be split between me and the company?

Comment: Did they promise you a split? Is the mention of a split in your contract? Have they done splits in the past?

Comment: Company gets 100%. You get 0%. Maybe a nice coffee mug.

Comment: There is no way to answer this.  It is all dependent on your company and your role.  Part of my job description and yearly expectation is that I HAVE to save the company 25K a year.

Comment: Yes they have offered a split of the 25k.  I have looked over the web on what the average of split is but can find nothing.

Comment: There is no "average" that makes any sense to you - as Jason has commented above, he is *expected* to save 25k a year as part of his normal duties, so he gets nothing. At this point, it's just a negotiation between you and your employer, just like anything else.

Comment: One way: take the $25k and subtract your salary, health care, office space costs, and any other benefits you received while you worked on this.  Be sure to deduct any expenses for any other employee that helped during this time.  If there is anything left over, take 10% of that.  Anything more than this means you are costing the company more to keep you than it's worth.

Answer (score 2):

1)  You should negotiate a split before you do the work.

2)  Take whatever they will give you.

3)  If you get more than a pat on the back count yourself lucky.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere how is that off in your head?  That is absolutely true and the correct way to go about it if you have any expectation to get extra pay for doing your job.  If you don't do that up front and have it signed then you ought not expect any extra compensation simply out of the kind heart of the 'company'.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I agree with your general point.  But how much worse is it after the fact if they come up to you and say it?  On a side note, I took the Q to be a self-initiated effort.  Either way, I think my points 2 and 3 show my take on the whole thing, but if one were to insist on asking for a share of the savings/profit, my suggestion of asking ahead of time is best imho.

Answer (score 2):

It may make you feel bad, but your salary is paid to you because the company hopes that you will make the company savings or additional profits that are worth more than your salary plus all the costs of hiring and employing you.

If you got paid $50,000 a year and you saved your company $50,000 a year or made them $50,000 profit a year, why would they even bother hiring you?

Comment: How do you know the OP is paid by salary?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you thought up the project, vested your personal time and resources into it, retained ownership (or some of the above) AND negotiated beforehand some sort of extra recompense beyond your salary, then expect nothing.

Possibly a bonus would be in order or a raise. If they prompted me I would ask for a pay raise. But realistically this is normal enough, I routinely save companies much more than that just by doing my job properly.